# WebServlet urlPatterns giving 404 Error

Tags: servlet-3.0

I was trying to use servlet Annotation .

This is my servlet as shown below and the context name is **Teste** 
I dont have any web.xml in my project .

```
package com;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
@WebServlet(name = "Mine", urlPatterns = { "/Mine" })
public class Mine extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Mine() {
        super();
        System.out.println("I am Called");
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String str = (String) session.getAttribute("salary");
        out.println("str is" + str);
    }
}
```

I am getting Error 404 when i was try to access in browser

[image]

Please let me know where i was doing Mistake .

Comment: Have you checked if the deployed Teste.war is present in server deployed applications?

Comment: From Eclipse IDE under Server tab, i have added this project to the tomcat server , and i am able to access the JSP Pages in that project . But when i checked the Server Webapps this project is not present .

Comment: There seems to be deployment issue rather programmatic error I guess.